# SIGCHLD and fork + waitpid() in a library

Tags: c, linux, fork, waitpid

I am writing a library that uses `fork()` and `exec()` to run external programs.
The code in my library runs as a separate thread.
The library thread needs to `waitpid()` on the forked process to know the exit code of the child process.

Unfortunately if the application using my library register a signal handler for `SIGCHLD`, the `waitpid()` calls returns with an error `ECHILD`.

How do I deal with this as a library with the application having minimal impact?
I essentially want the child to remain a zombie and have control over when it's reaped.

Can I insulate myself from what the application decides to do?
Can I hijack the signal handler in some way and put it back after my `waitpid` is done?

Comment: You could fork your *own* process to handle your own process handling, and have the library communicate with the stand-alone process through pipes or some such [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). Then you could also install your own signal-handlers, like e.g. your own `SIGCHLD` instead of relying only on `waitpid`.

Comment: Seconded. Unix domain datagram sockets are often useful for this. Unix domain sockets allow you to pass file descriptors, for example pipe descriptors to/from the forked grandchild process, back to the parent, using ancillary messages. Unix domain datagram messages are not reordered, and retain message boundaries (so a receive with a sufficiently large buffer will always receive complete messages); these properties make the communication simple and robust. You might not even need a separate thread for this approach; the helper process should suffice.

Comment: This is an age-old problem with the Unix fork/wait model, and I'm not sure there are any simple solutions.

Comment: Yeah seems like a complicated problem indeed. Thanks for the responses ! Since my library is used by a very controlled set of users with known functionality I'm just tempted to say "DON'T register signal handlers".

Comment: As I understand it, the standard `system()` function suffers from the same problem.

Comment: Instead of telling them not to install signal handlers, provide & document a function they should call at the beginning of their SIGCHLD handler to keep your library happy -- and take care that that function be signal-safe. And hope that other libraries the program uses don't do their process management themselves, but leave it to the main program, as your library should've done, too ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Freeing resources allocated by a library is an application bug. It's the same in principle as if the appliction did something like `free(yourlib_create_context(...))`, although of course the consequences are less severe. There's no reason to try to support this kind of nonsensical application behavior; just document that it's invalid.

If you want to "shield" against this sort of programming error, mask signals an then call `abort` if `waitpid` fails with `ECHLD`. This will unconditionally terminate the process without the applicating having any chance to catch it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do just as [`system`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system) does:

> system() executes a command specified in command by calling /bin/sh -c command, and returns after the command has been completed. During execution of the command, **SIGCHLD will be blocked**, and SIGINT and SIGQUIT will be ignored.

An outline could be

```
pid_t pid;
sigset_t block, backup;

sigemptyset(&block);
sigaddset(&block, SIGCHLD);

sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &block, &backup);

if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
    // error handle
} else if (pid == 0) {    // child
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &backup, NULL);

    // ...
} else {
    // waitpid

    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &backup, NULL);
}

// ...
```